# How do I get soot out of my clothes blankets and pillows?

Tags: smell, fabric, wood

We had a house fire a couple of weeks ago and now there is soot all over my blankets, cloth wall hangings, dressers, plastic drawers and even my goo gollies. How do I get it out of washable colored fabric and off wood and plastic without damaging or discoloring it?

Comment: This isn't so much as 'one hack' than expert knowledge, such as given here [How to Clean Soot After a Fire](https://b-air.com/2017/10/clean-soot-fire/).

Comment: What are "goo gollies"?

Answer (score 2):

Use mouthwash in your wash, I used it in the bleach cycle.  It only takes 2-3 capsful and works wonderfully!

You can also use mouthwash to clean plastic things. I used a Mr.Clean sponge with a mix of mouthwash and water and it cleaned the soot off and took the smell away!
I washed all of our dishes and silverware in the house with mouthwash in the dishwater.  For the more stubborn stains I dipped the sponge straight into the mouthwash and it wiped the soot right off and took the smell off.

For my plastic 4 drawer dresser I used the sponge dipped in mouthwash and a smidgeon of Dawn if I needed it. worked great!